# Define product bundles with different quantities in commercetools

Tags: commercetools

I want to model a bundle in `commercetools` which contains two different products and both these products have different quantities in it.

For ex:

#### Bundle A

- Product X | QTY: 1
- Product Y | QTY: 3

#### Bundle B

- Product A | QTY: 2
- Product B | QTY: 5

I have tried modelling this using custom objects but it seems it is not a good fit. I am looking for other possible solutions to achieve this. Also, I would be interested in solutions that support `expansions` so that I can retrieve the details of the products in the bundle without an additional request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to model this similar to what is described in our product bundle tutorial in the commercetools documentation.
https://docs.commercetools.com/tutorials/product-bundle-api#top